# Exponent an arbitrary number by a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I know `np.exp2(x)` exists that calculates `2^x` where `x` is a numpy array, however, I am looking for a method that does `K^x` where `K` is any arbitrary number. 
Is there any elegant way of doing it rather than stretching out `K` to the shape of `x` and doing a piecewise exponent?

Comment: @tel: The "piecewise" seems to make things more confusing rather than less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standard Python exponentiation operator `**`:

```
K**x
```

For example, if you have:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
K = 3

print(K**x)
```

The output is:

```
[ 3  9 27]
```

#### Notes

For Python classes, the behavior of the binary `**` operator is implemented via the `__pow__`, `__rpow__`, and  `__ipow__` magic methods (the reality for `np.ndarray` is slightly more complicated since it's implemented in the C layer, but that's not actually important here). For Numpy arrays, these magic methods in turn appear to call [`numpy.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.power.html), so you can expect that `**` will have the same behavior as documented for `numpy.power`. In particular,

> Note that an integer type raised to a negative integer power will raise a ValueError.

Comment: small note: cast `K` to a float or else negative numbers in the array will throw an error.

Comment: @Vj- I added a note about the implementation of `**`, including where it mentions that particular error in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can just use [`numpy.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

```
arr = numpy.array([1,2,3])
print(numpy.power(3,arr)) # Outputs [ 3  9 27]
```